# What's wrong with my appcache manifest test?

Tags: php, html, https, html5-appcache

I'm trying to test **Appcache** manifest:

```
<?php

// reference: http://diveintohtml5.info/offline.html

header( "Content-Type: text/cache-manifest" );
header( "Cache-Control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate" );

?>CACHE MANIFEST

# todo

/cachetest/tryme/vid/missouristate
```

Now this appears to have the right headers in Network inspector, and is linked to at the top of a html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html manifest="/cachetest/cache.manifest/index.php" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
```

However, there is zero evidence this is actually working. If it were working, it should not show any other items, unless it had a NETWORK * setting in that file, as described [here](http://diveintohtml5.info/offline.html):

> Finally, let’s examine the network section. The network section in
>   this cache manifest also has just a single line, a line that contains
>   just a single character (*). This character has special meaning in a
>   network section. It’s called the “online whitelist wildcard flag.”
>   That’s a fancy way of saying that anything that isn’t in the appcache
>   can still be downloaded from the original web address, as long as you
>   have an internet connection. This is important for an “open-ended”
>   offline web application. It means that, while you’re browsing this
>   hypothetical offline-enabled Wikipedia online, your browser will fetch
>   images and videos and other embedded resources normally, even if they
>   are on a different domain. (This is common in large websites, even if
>   they aren’t part of an offline web application. HTML pages are
>   generated and served locally, while images and videos are served from
>   a CDN on another domain.) Without this wildcard flag, our hypothetical
>   offline-enabled Wikipedia would behave strangely when you were online
>   — specifically, it wouldn’t load any externally-hosted images or
>   videos!

This looks like similar web-apps that work offline, though I have to wonder if I have to set up https on localhost or local-ip to get the browser to even recognize it.

I remember seeing something recently about Appcache now requiring https as Serviceworker requires https as well. Is that something I have to set up in test environment for this to work in the latest browsers? Can I change an about:config to use on plain http? Or am I missing something else?

Comment: Downvoted why? Because MDN says it's deprecated? It is supported by browsers though.

Comment: I am not the downvoter, but I do not understand what you mean by "zero evidence this is working" or "it should not show any other items".  When I tried your code I see the browser get the html, get the manifest, get the resource, then double check the manifest, as specified. applicationCache.status also says 1 instead of 0, indicating cache is functional. All without https.  How do you expect it to work?

Comment: @Sheepy Sorry I wasn't clear, I have included quote from the docs I was reading that should clarify that part.

Answer (score 1):

You are not doing anything wrong.

*Appcache does not work in Firefox.* (at least for me in Firefox 42.0)

But it does work in Chrome (I tried on 46.0.2490.86 (latest)).

Some testing pages:
http://appcache-demo.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/without-network/

http://appcache-demo.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/with-network/

http://appcache-demo.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/offline-iframe/

And of course you can make your own empty cache manifest file and see for yourself.

Good Luck

<sub>Source of testing pages:
http://alistapart.com/article/application-cache-is-a-douchebag</sub>

Comment: Really? It's supposed to work. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Using_the_application_cache#Browser_compatibility

Comment: Overdrive Media's offline library book reader works in Firefox, and it has `<html manifest="/_d/cache.manifest">` Does the .manifest file type mean you have to set up some special htaccess or server setup to have php(for example) serve a .manifest file?

Comment: Yes, but that's just another way to write `Content-Type: text/cache-manifest`,  I was doing that , in apache .htaccess I added `AddType text/cache-manifest .appcache` and I also tried `AddType text/cache-manifest .manifest`, but Firefox doesn't care what's in that file, it caches everything that it wants, but same setup does work in Chrome, without changing anything.

Answer (score 1):

Check the following steps to see why your code is not working, then maybe your code will work.

- you are using `php` file, but The recommended file extension for manifest files is: ".appcache"
- if you use `.appcache` then don't need to set header, browser will get `text/cache-manifest` header for `.appcache` extension.
- in manifest The first line, `CACHE MANIFEST`, is required. so remove php code from first.
- `CACHE MANIFEST` section only get resource like JS, CSS, images etc.. I think the name of the page you entered is incorrect.

And after checking the steps above, the manifest will probably be ready as follows.

name will be : `index.appcache`

```
CACHE MANIFEST
# todo
/cachetest/images/1.jpg
/cachetest/css/style.css

NETWORK:
/login.php

FALLBACK:
/html/ /cachetest/offline.html
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html manifest="/cachetest/cache.manifest/index.appcache" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
```

The names of the list of files are given for example.